# aspx ListBoxis not working (SelectedIndex)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have this in my aspx page:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBoxDelete_SelectedIndexChanged1"></asp:ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   ListBoxDelete.Items.Clear();
   List<string> itens = new List<string>();
   for(var item in itens){
      ListBoxDelete.Items.Add(item);
   }
}

protected void ListBoxDelete_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e){
   int x = ListBoxDelete.SelectedIndex;
   doSomething(x);
}
```

My SelectedIndex is not working... If I'm not mistaken, the value is always -1. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686319/listbox-not-getting-selected-items?rq=1)

Comment: Show code where you binding this ListBox

Comment: Probably you miss `If(!IsPostBack)` in `page_load` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follow and try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   ListBoxDelete.Items.Clear();
   List<string> itens = new List<string>();
   for(var item in itens){
      ListBoxDelete.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `Page_Load` with if [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     ListBoxDelete.Items.Clear();
     List<string> itens = new List<string>();
      for(var item in itens){
       ListBoxDelete.Items.Add(item);
     }
  }
}
```